# How to programmatically create a multidimensional array using a while loop

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to use PHP to read through a CSV file and build arrays based on matches of a specific row.
The CSV file contents look like this:

```
id, name, qty, price
1,Jeff,2,59,
2,Tom,3,36,
3,Lenny,2,25,
4,Tom,5,69,
5,Jeff,3,19,
6,Tom,2,75,
```

I'm using a 'while' loop to read through the CSV file:

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($h, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
```

The idea is: If, while reading through the CSV file, a match is found with $row[1] like this...

```
if($row[1] == 'Tom') {
```

...an array is created that would look like this when the 'while loop' completes:

```
array(
'item_1' => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Tom', 'qty' => 3, 'price' => 36),
'item_2' => array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Tom', 'qty' => 5, 'price' => 69),
'item_3' => array('id' => 6, 'name' => 'Tom', 'qty' => 2, 'price' => 75)
);
```

(The "item number" for the first element would need to start with "item_1" and increment by 1 as a new element is added).

If this is possible, what logic would need to be used?

Comment: Why?  `item_1` or `item_2` is no more descriptive than `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign an element to the result array.

```
$result = [];
$index = 1;
$cols = fgetcsv($h, ","); // get header row
while (($row = fgetcsv($h, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($row[1] == 'Tom') {
        $result['item_' . $index++] = array_combine($cols, $row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or get the first row before the loop and `array_combine` with the following rows.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I was thinking of using `array_combine`, but didn't feel like writing it out. Didn't notice the header row.

Comment: @Aedan No, because post-increment returns the old value. You would be correct if I wrote `++$index`

Comment: @Barmar What if I didn't have the header row in the CSV file? What would I use in place of `array_combine`?

Comment: You can just assign a variable like `$cols = ["id", "name", "qty", "price"];`

Comment: This solved my issue. Thank you so much for your assistance, @Barmar!